# Is it possible to log off windows 8.1 on wireless mouse disconnect?

Tags: mouse, windows-8.1, powershell

I'm running a laptop with windows 8.1, I often run it in public places where sometimes I leave it for a few minutes and I started to think would it be possible to log off and log on when I switch off and on my wireless mouse.

I'm using microsoft wireless mouse 4000 it connects to computer via nano adaptor.
Laptop itself if it is relevant is Samsung Chronos 7.

Maybe it is not possible, I don't know, but I thought I will ask. I don't have much of such programming experience, but I'm web developer and do sometimes play with powershell (very novice still), so I was thinking maybe it is possible to somehow track when mouse connects to computer?

Thanks for replies!

**UPDATE**

Thank you all for helping out and pointing to possible flaws of such feature. Something to think about. But for now, the whole idea is to check whether it is possible, and if it is, how hard it would be to make it. More like DIY project if you like.

Comment: I am not sure how to take the idea all the way, but if you want a list of USB devices that are connected, you can use `Get-WmiObject Win32_USBControllerDevice`

Comment: That's seems rather like _Zero-Interaction Authentication_ [PDF](http://www.sigmobile.org/awards/mobicom2002-student.pdf) [ACM](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=570647).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you really want to use this, despite previous answers - use the task scheduler and get to know the event id for mouse connect/disconnect (the trigger), and use as action the logout (`shutdown` command) / login (I don't know how to log in a user from cmd line) of windows.

Edit:

I found a utility that can log in a user from the command line, which would suit your needs:

http://www.softtreetech.com/24x7/archive/51.htm

Here is an article on USB device event ID's:

http://dfstream.blogspot.nl/2014/01/the-windows-7-event-log-and-usb-device.html

Comment: Thanks for you help, it seems like theoretically that's possible so I will mark your answer as the right one. Also very nice links, especially the one about USB device event ID's, looks very promising!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like an [X - Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Just use win+l to lock the device when you're not using it. Simple enough. What you're trying to do sounds like a bad idea for a number of reasons the least of which is security, and the amount of time "saved" in comparison to the amount of time you'll spend trying to get this to work.

Comment: I see what you mean by that, but in this case I'm fully aware of simple shortcuts that are available to lock the PC. Yet the real problem is whether the idea that I have is possible, and could I make it with some internet folks advice. Its more like DIY project, which doesn't necessarily have to be the most optimum solution to the problem.
I'm sorry if I failed to reflect that in my question though.

Comment: Just about anything is possible, whether or not it's a good idea is still relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it is possible (with the help of some third party software) it would bring a lot of problems with it. What if the battery runs out on your Wireless Mouse ? What if your Wireless Mouse is malfunctioning or happens to loose temporary the connection with your Laptop ? Also (I don't know) but it might be that your mouse is saving energy by turning its self off when you are not using it for a specific amount of time. All this would lock your system, even though you do not want it.

I suggest every time you turn your back on your Laptop in the Public make sure to hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on your Windows 8.1 system.

Comment: It works exactly, like you said. Receiver sends usb packet when mouse is down, but mouse goes down every few seconds. The only way is monitor conection of receiver itself, but that lacks convenience.

Comment: And what if someone has the same type of mouse working on the same frequency? He'll easily be able to unlock his computer.